# Laravel - Streaming video from storage directory

Tags: php, laravel, stream, video-streaming, streaming

I did exactly what these links explain:

https://laravel.io/forum/10-06-2014-streaming-video-files-with-laravel

https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/993d400739dd2e9aa47d

[Retrieve video from Laravel Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872078/retrieve-video-from-laravel-storage)

NONE OF THEM WORKED!

My code:

```
View:

<video controls>
    <source src="{{ $package->video }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>


Model:

public function getVideoAttribute() {
    // 1:
    $path = storage_path('app/package/video.mp4');
    $stream = new \App\Helpers\VideoStream($path);
    $stream->start();

    // 2:
    $fileContents = Storage::disk('local')->get('app/package/video.mp4');
    $response = \Response::make($fileContents, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', "video/mp4");

    return $response;
}
```

and the results:

[image: stream video 1] As you can see it is empty.

[image: stream video 2] And this one doesn't even let the page load and returns the page as an empty video.

Comment: Shouldn't the value of "src" attribute be a string? Seems like you are setting it to be a stream, which is impossible.
The "src" should contain a URL to controller, where you need to place your code returning a $response;

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56872547/6051839 with more attention, please.

Comment: Yeah, I know it was a shame :)) Thank you very much, I should have used a URL not the content of the video. I got it wrong with `<img src=" content of the image ">`.